# Height auto doesn't working in div inside div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, padding

I found many topics but I couldn't find solution for my problem so I started with topic. I have a  container with padding top and bottom. Then, I added another  inside container. Second  included image and content, but if I want to display full content my image will disappear because  container doesn't automatically expand height. Here are my HTML code:

http://codepen.io/thehung1724/pen/Fvgxz

Hope anyone can help me out. Thank in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The final generated HTML has a container around your content called `contentHolderUnit` with a fixed height of `355.64040404040406px`. That's why it isn't resizing to show all the content. This is probably being done by whatever "carousel" system you're using, so you should check the docs for that system to find out if you can adjust the height.

Comment: You can change height value to check it. I already changed but it still couldn't show all content.

Comment: I edited to height: auto !important but nothing changed.